# Does complaints about leaving hours inappropriate?

Tags: professionalism, work-environment, company-culture, politics, complaint

I am in the following situation:
A person in a senior position is sloppy in his job and that affects our team. As a result we spend many times working overtimes to reach deadlines but he *always* leaves on time no matter what. This annoys everyone especially since we do the overtime because he never does an extra effort to deliver his part as we do since he leaves on time no matter what.
So if *we* did not do overtime compensating for his indifference nothing would be done on time.
My question is: when complaining are making comments about the leaving hours inappropriate?

Comment: How well prepared are you to know what time he starts work and how much work he does in a day? Consider carefully what you do know and what you may assume here to some extent.

Comment: @JBKing:I know because I see him.And concerning to how much work that I don't know.What I do know is that he never delivers anything on time to us

Comment: We might be able to help with a question about how to approach him, but when you should do it is out of scope.  It is asking for bad subjective opinions.  Please See [this blog post for more on Good Subjective versus Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)

Comment: @Chad:What do you mean "when you should do it"?

Comment: @Jim read the blog post I linked.  Then try to revise your question to fit those guidelines

Answer (score 3):

He's rightly working his contracted hours. The issue is not one of overtime - you should be discussing the quality of work if that's an issue.

Perhaps you should ask yourself why you continue to give free work to the company? Would they provide free services/products to their customers?

Comment: But our overtime is caused by not him doing any extra effort. Had he taken the responsibility and say to the management "this can not be done as I need to leave 5pm sharp" that would be fine. But he does not say anything and we are paying the price like fools

Comment: @L_7337:Actually part of the problem is his poor work quality that makes us do the extra work. The complaints are a lot but his indifference for us and leaving on time is really annoying. But I don't know if it is professional to bring this up

Comment: @Jim - the answer being provided here is that not professional to talk about his hours but that it is appropriate to talk about the quality of his work.

Comment: Good Answers here explain why they are correct not just what the answer is.  This answer lacks the why.

Answer (score 2):

It's inappropriate to discuss working hours from a subordinate to a supervisor, largely because that shouldn't be your problem or issue. After all, the boss *can* drive his/her company into the ground if he/she wants to. Alternatively, it would really be an issue for your boss's boss to deal with, if it really is a problem.

The real issue here is that you are not receiving the resources or tools to be able to do your job, which directly affects your performance at that job. This is something that you can professionally discuss with your boss, either one-on-one or as a group.

Comment: Who said it is my boss?